# Exception in Tkinter callback variables editing

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\*****\Downloads\*****\*****\builder.py", line 277, in assemble_source_code
    save_configuration()
  File "c:\Users\*****\Downloads\*****\PySilon-malware-main\builder.py", line 237, in save_configuration
    config['FUNCTIONALITY']['testing'] = str(cbvar_testing.get())
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're assuming `cbvar_testing` points to an instance of `StringVar` or one of the other variables (`IntVar`, etc), but it is actually pointing to an instance of `Checkbutton`. Since an instance of `Checkbutton` doesn't have a `get` method, you get the error that you get.